# Alfresco : Import FileSystem permissions w/ Bulk Filesystem Import Tool

Tags: file-permissions, import, alfresco, bulk

I have Alfresco 4.2.c installed on a Windows Server 2012, linked, sync and SSO to a LDAP (working great).

I'm trying to use BFI (https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-bulk-filesystem-import/) to import a filesystem linked to the users of the LDAP (permissions of the FS are set on the users of the AD). 
But BFI doesn't import the permissions : however I try, if it does import the files / folders, it doesn't keep the permissions.

Example : I connect as Admin on BFI, and import a file that is owned by User1. In alfresco, although User1 exists (imported via LDAP), it's owned by Admin, and the permissions are set to readable to all.
Any one has an idea on how to import permissions ?

If i'm not using the good tool, which one should I try ? I've been trying Open Migrate and Talend, but none of them seems to do the trick (or I'd appreciate having a tutorial that would explain that to me : I wasn't able to find one... :/)

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1):

As stated by its name, the bulk file import tool does a bulk import. This means that only binary content is imported. Any metadata has to be defined in the xml file that define the import.
ACEs (and so ACLs), associations and are not handled at all as shown bellow:

https://github.com/pmonks/alfresco-bulk-import/issues/8

However using some scripting language to gather fioesystem acl and restore them using one of the many api alfresco provides should be possible without too much work.

Comment: Please star / comment on the above issue if this is a high priority for you.  An experimental fork that added support for importing ACEs / ACLs was developed some years back but performance was so poor it wasn't merged into the mainline.

In general Alfresco doesn't support heavy ACE / ACL write loads very well, and it may be better to write permissions as a post-processing step during off periods (i.e. when the system can be safely destabilised).

Comment: Hi Peter. Long time no see! I can't say that it is something I would really need on a daily basis, but it's something I would have used at least twice since I left alfresco in project where people where migrating from plain and dumb file server to alfresco ecm.